# Pom.xml with local jar and concurrent dependency

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependency-management

Here is the situation :

I want to use a locally installed jar in a springboot project. I included the dependency to this artifact in my pom.xml :

```java
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mycie.myjar</groupId>
        <artifactId>myjar</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

This jar uses the artifact snakeyaml with version 1.16

But in my main project, Springboot uses snakeyaml version 1.23

The concurrency seems to cause some issues when running the application.
Do you have any idea on the good practices to tackle this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maven will only let one of the jars into the resulting application. You can find out by calling `mvn dependency:list` which jar Maven chose.

The resulting problem cannot be really solved by Maven. Instead, you need to figure out which version of snakeyaml works for all scenarios. Since one of the jars belongs to you, it is probably best to just update the dependency of `myjar` to avoid this problem.

Comment: Thanks! In my case, both versions are imposed by external constraints : myjar, and springboot. So this could simply mean that myjar is not compatible with the version of springboot I am using. Is it correct?

Comment: @plalanne Yes, it could. But what this answer is suggesting is to see if you can update snakeyaml in your jar.

If that's not an option, and if snakeyaml 1.23 doesn't break retrocompatibility with 1.16, you can also exclude the 1.16 jar from your main project's pom by adding an `<exclude>` to the dependency on `myJar`

And if that second option is not an option either, then yes, it probably means your version of myJar isn't compatible with the Spring Boot version you are using.

Comment: you can try to find a version that is compatible with both artifacts and impose the version with `<dependencyManagement>`.

Comment: @FrenchFigaro `exclude` is the wrong mechanism here. If you want to set a dependency, use `<dependencyManagement>`.